# Try...Catch...Finally To check for string VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, exception, try-catch, average

I am trying to make a program from a program that I previously made that will average together 10 numbers, and catch an exception if letters are entered.  The Old code without the check for letters was

```
Module Module1
Sub Main()
    Dim Input As Decimal
    Console.WriteLine("Press the numbers you would like to average and press enter after each number.")
    Console.WriteLine("After the tenth number all the numbers will be averaged together.")
    Input = Console.ReadLine
    Console.WriteLine((Input + Console.ReadLine + Console.ReadLine + Console.ReadLine + Console.ReadLine + Console.ReadLine + Console.ReadLine + Console.ReadLine + Console.ReadLine + Console.ReadLine) / 10)
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
End Module
```

The new program I currently have is the following, I'm having all sorts of problems so any help would be appreciated.

```
Module Module1

Public Sub Main()
    Dim input As Object

    Console.WriteLine("Press the numbers you would like to average and press enter after each number.")
    Console.WriteLine("After the tenth number all the numbers will be averaged together.")
    input = Console.ReadLine
    If Char.IsNumber(Console.ReadLine) Then
        Console.WriteLine((Console.ReadLine + Console.ReadLine + Console.ReadLine + Console.ReadLine + Console.ReadLine + Console.ReadLine + Console.ReadLine + Console.ReadLine + Console.ReadLine + Console.ReadLine) / 10)
        Console.ReadKey()
    End If
    If Not IsNumeric(Console.ReadLine) Then
        Try
        Catch ex As System.Exception
            System.Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number")
        Finally
            System.Console.WriteLine("Try again without entering any letters")
        End Try
        Console.ReadKey()
    End If



End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Could you be slightly more explicit about the errors that you're getting?

Comment: define "all sorts of problems"...mindreading skills are at the cleaners

Comment: For some reason in stead of the numbers being averaged, they are getting multiplied in some strange way, and I am having to enter 3 different letters before it displays the exception message.

Comment: Every time you call `Console.ReadLine` it will go back to the user for input.  Only two of those checks have an isnumeric.  Also, you have nothing in the Try block.

Answer (score 2):

Try/Catch does not work that way. The block would execute any code between Try and Catch and if an exception occurs in this code it would go to the Catch-Code. The Finally code is executed afterwards no matter what. Your approach is not very straightforward. I would suggest something like:

```
Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter ten numbers.")
    Dim nums As New List(Of Double)
    Do
        Dim input As String = Console.ReadLine
        If IsNumeric(input) Then
            nums.Add(CDbl(input))
            Console.WriteLine("Ok. Please enter " & (10 - nums.Count).ToString & " more numbers.")
        ElseIf input = "exit" Then
            Exit Sub
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter only numeric values. Please try again.")
        End If
    Loop Until nums.Count >= 10
    Dim res As Double = 0
    For i = 0 To nums.Count - 1
        res += nums(i)
    Next
    Console.WriteLine("----------------")
    Console.WriteLine("Average value: " & (res / nums.Count).ToString)
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

This does not use Try/Catch. Instead it checks if each line entered is numeric. If so the number is added to a List(Of Double) for later calculation of the average. If it is not numeric a message will be displayed and you have to try again. This goes on until 10 valid numbers are entered. Then the average is calculated and displayed.

Comment: List has an Average Method and a Sum Method that you can use instead of iterating through the list to add it up.

Comment: That is true. I just never think of these for some reason :-)

Comment: @Jens Thank you for your help but for this specific program I have to use Try...Catch....Finally in some way.  How would you suggest I do that?